# Unable to add data into Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Im getting the following two errors when trying to upload my JSON into Firebase:

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0h20.png)

Factory:

```
angular
    .module("ngClassifieds")
    .factory("classifiedsFactory", function($http, $firebaseArray){
(
    var ref = new Firebase('https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/');
    return {
        ref: $firebaseArray(ref)
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
.controller("classifiedsCtrl", function($scope, $http, classifiedsFactory, $mdSidenav, $mdToast, $mdDialog)
```

I am using the following code to upload my JSON into firebase.

```
var firebase = classifiedsFactory.ref //we have a variable pointing to our classifiedsFactory reference

angular.forEach(data, function (item) {

    firebase.$add(item);
});
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: Instead of posting a link to an image with the error message, please post the actual error message (including the entire stack trace). That way it's searchable, doesn't require an external image (links tend to disappear way faster than you might expect) and we don't have to click a link to see the error.

Comment: You have an extra `(` in the first snippet. That's what the JavaScript engine is complaining about.

Comment: @Frank ... oh gosh Frank... i feel inadequate for not doin my due diligence here.. thanks for the feedback.. it works all right now.

Comment: @Frank and yes, i get it about not postin image links.. thanks for your help